# If $\sum_{k=4}^{143} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} = a - \sqrt{b}$, then $a$ and $b$ respectively are

Tags: summation, real-numbers

If $\sum_{k=4}^{143} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} = a - \sqrt{b}$, then $a$ and $b$ respectively are

1. 10 and 0
2. -10 and 4
3. 10 and 4
4. -10 and 0

---

This question is from the book, [Mathematics, Class 9 (The IIT Foundation Series)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34705751-mathematics-class-9) , page number 1.25. The answer key present in the book says the first option as the correct answer. I need an explanation to solve this question. Till now I have tried to rationalize $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}}$ found that $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} = \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$. I am not sure what to do next.

Thanks!

Comment: Try writing out the first few terms of the sum in the "rationalised" form.

Comment: What you found is very helpful. You now have a telescoping series with a lot of cancellation.

Comment: I suggest you don't look at the two answers posted so far: they make this thing look harder than it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four alternatives result when calculating $a-\sqrt{b}$ in
\begin{align*}
&(10,0)&10-\sqrt{0}&=10\tag{1.}\\
&(-10,4)&-10-\sqrt{4}&=-12\tag{2.}\\
&(10,4)&10-\sqrt{4}&=8\tag{3.}\\
&(-10,0)&-10-\sqrt{0}&=-10\tag{4.}
\end{align*}

> We can now use OPs telescoping approach and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=4}^{143} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}}}
> &=\sum_{k=4}^{143}\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)\\
> &=\sqrt{143+1}-\sqrt{4}\\
> &=12-2\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=10}
> \end{align*}
> showing (1.) is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! We need more people like you on this website.

Comment: @AbhigyanKumar: You're welcome! Many thanks for your nice comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your sum $$\sum_{k=4}^{143} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} = a - \sqrt{b}$$ converges to $10$ which means that $10 = a - \sqrt b$. After solving this equation we get $a = 10$ $and$ $b = 0$. Hence option(1) is correct. Your approach to rationalize it was correct. If we rationalize it we get $\sqrt(k+1) - \sqrt k$. If we substitute the value of 4 in the equation we get $\sqrt5 - \sqrt4$, we then move on to the next value of $k$ which is $5$ which becomes $\sqrt6 - \sqrt5$. Till now we got, $(\sqrt5 - \sqrt4) + (\sqrt6 - \sqrt5) + (\sqrt7 - \sqrt6) + ... + (\sqrt144 - \sqrt143)$. Now we can cancel out the $\sqrt5$ of the first bracket from the $\sqrt5$ of the second bracket and we will cancel out each and every term. After the cancellation we get $-\sqrt4 + \sqrt144$ and we get 10, which is your answer. Now we can equate it with $a - \sqrt b$ and we get $a = 10$ and $b = 0$